# Fatal error: Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []):[]):

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, codeigniter-4

i'm using codeigniter 4 and i try to implement Login with Google.
so far so good until i got this error when i try to get the result. here the error message:

`Fatal error: Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency($message, array $context = []) in C:\xampp\htdocs\postlite\app\Libraries\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php on line 669`

can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Edit your question to add your PHP version, and maybe the installed versions of the 2 packages involved.

Comment: Which version of monolog are you using? If 3+, then it could be this known issue : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/11246

Comment: oh my god. you're right. the problem was on monolog and psr/log version.
i solve it with just downgrading monolog to ^2.5 and psr/log version to ^2.0 in the composer

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was enabled PHP PSR module.
Laravel 10x does not use this module anymore.
I disabled it on Ubuntu by running the command 'phpdismod psr'
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the file php.ini, search for this line:

```
extension=php_psr.dll
```

Change it to:

```
;extension=php_psr.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem arises from the php-psr extension installed on the system, To see if you have the extension installed, run this command.

```bash
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep php
```

search something like

```
php8.2-psr
php7.4-psr
```

Depending on the version of PHP that you have installed on your system, proceed to remove the package.

```
sudo apt remove php8.2-psr
```

that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a Docker container using Alpine Linux (namely the `php:8.2-fpm-alpine` image), and the way I fixed it is by adding `monolog/monolog` version `^2.9` in my `composer.json`. This (`monolog/monolog`) was a dependency for another package I used, and version 3+ seems to not be compatible with the `php:8.x-fpm-alpine` images.

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your `monolog` to `^2.5` and `psr/log` version to `^2.0`

Change your `libraries/composer.json` like this:

```json
{
    "name": "google/login",
    "description": "appname google login",
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "2.15.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^2.5",
        "psr/log": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

and execute

`composer update`