# Laravel 10 Fatal error: Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXeKh.png) I have a problem with Hosting, I am using Laravel v10.16.0 and PHP v8.1.18

Below is the error that is displaying

> Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void must be compatible with PsrExt\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency($message, array $context = []) in /var/www/###/data/www/******.**/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 669\n

How to rectify this above issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696889/fatal-error-declaration-of-monolog-loggeremergencystringablestring-message maybe helpful